# FastAPI with uvicorn getting 404 Not Found error

Tags: python, fastapi, uvicorn

I'm trying (failing) to set up a simple FastAPI project and run it with uvicorn.
This is my code:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

app.get('/')

def hello_world():
    return{'hello':'world'}

app.get('/abc')

def abc_test():
    return{'hello':'abc'}
```

This is what I run from the terminal:

```
PS C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Self pace study\Python\Dev\day 14> uvicorn server2:app   
INFO:     Started server process [3808]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     127.0.0.1:60391 - "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found
INFO:     127.0.0.1:60391 - "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found
```

As you see, I get a 404 Not found. What could be the reason? Some network-related stuff, possibly firewall/vpn blocking this connection or something else? I'm new to this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need *decorate* the router using ***`@app.get(...)`***, not just `app.get()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use a decorator like this: `@app.get('/')`.  Take a look at the [FastAPI Docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/first-steps/).

Additionally, take a look at how decorators work in general to get a better idea of how things work behind the scenes.

Some resources for you:

[python docs](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/)

[one of many articles I was able to find](https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/)

[another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12046883/python-decorator-can-someone-please-explain-this)

Comment: Thanks. That was the issue.

Comment: Something else, so that I don't open another question - if you happen to know - I am asked every time after I restart the terminal to install fastAPI, uvicorn and pipenv again, otherwise it behaves like they don't exist....? Why would that be? Visual Studio Code, Python 3.8

Comment: That kind of sounds like a virtual environment issue to me, where VSCode or your terminal are not picking it up correctly.  Are you using the VSCode integrated terminal? Maybe look into setting up VSCode for a python environment [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments).  I think that should at least get you in a decent spot to do some more research, after which I think another question would be appropriate if you aren't able to find anything.  Since you're using pipenv, VSCode should integrate with that nicely and see everything that you've installed via `pipenv install`.

Comment: Yep this is exactly how VSCode is set up to use Python (because I set it up a few weeks ago using the same guide as the link you pasted) and I use the VSCode terminal. Anyway thanks for your help mate I'll keep digging and post if I find out what the issue was. Cheers.

Answer (score 6):

By now you'd probably have figured it out. In order to get MWE running, you'd use the microservice's endpoint [decorators](https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/) before each function definition. The following snippet should get your issue solved.
It assumes that you have the following structure:

```bash
.
+-- main.py
+-- static
|   +-- favicon.ico
+-- templates
|   +-- index.html
```

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse, FileResponse
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
import os

app = FastAPI()

app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")

templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")

@app.get('/')
def hello_world():
    return{'hello':'world'}

@app.get('/favicon.ico')
async def favicon():
    file_name = "favicon.ico"
    file_path = os.path.join(app.root_path, "static", file_name)
    return FileResponse(path=file_path, headers={"Content-Disposition": "attachment; filename=" + file_name})

@app.get('/abc')
def abc_test():
    return{'hello':'abc'}
```

So you'd be all set to run your first app using the FastAPI default ASGI server.

`(env)$: uvicorn main:app --reload --host 0.0.0.0 --port ${PORT}`