# Where I am making a mistake with this decorator code?

Tags: python

I am trying to understand the concept of decorators in python when we have different arguments (In fact I am not sure how to pass arguments to the decorator). I have written the small and simple code below but I am not able to run it:

```
def advance(*arg, function):
    result = a * function(b, c)
    print(result)

@advance
def Sum1(b, c):
    return b + c

print(Sum1(1, 2, 3))
```

When running the code, I get `TypeError: advance() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'function'.`

Comment: `Sum1` becomes `arg[0]`, it's impossible to pass a keyword argument to the decorator (although you can to a decorator _factory_) using the `@` syntax. Also `a`, `b` and `c` are all undefined inside the decorator, which doesn't return a function to replace the wrapped function.

Comment: The way you have it written `advance` would only take one argument, and that argument would be a function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python decorator? - can someone please explain this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12046883/python-decorator-can-someone-please-explain-this)

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/q/5929107/3001761, https://stackoverflow.com/q/739654/3001761

Comment: The function is the *first* argument to `advance`, not the last. It helps to write out the use without decorator syntax. You define `Sum1`, then imagine `Sum1 = advance(Sum1)`.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1594484/13354437) is probably the best resource around for understanding and implementing decorators. It's a long read but it's worth it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decorator has to return a new function, so you would like to have something like:

```py
def advance(function):
    def wrapped(a, b, c):
        return a * function(b, c)
    return wrapped

@advance
def Sum1(b, c):
    return b + c

print(Sum1(10, 2, 3))
```