# limit some users to only one page in Django

Tags: django, django-authentication

I want to know how do i limit the access of specific users to only one page once they're logged in.

I have in my User model

```
deactivated = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

If the user is logged in and their account is deactivated I want to only show them a deactivation page. I don't want to allow them to go anywhere else on the website unless they activate their account again.
What's the best and the most simple way to implement that?

**EDIT:** I can't afford going through every view I have and attach a decorator to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use the decorator approach, your best bet is to write a [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/?from=olddocs) that checks if `request.user` is activated or not, then redirect (to a page where they can reactivate their account preferably) when necessary.

Roughly you'd want something like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect


class DeactivatedRedirectMiddleware(object):

    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.user and not request.user.is_anonymous():
            if request.user.deactivated and request.get_full_path() != '/some/url/':
                # redirect here
                return redirect('/some/url/')
        # ...
```

Comment: Okay this works I think. but now I'm in a redirect loop. because even going to `/some/url/` redirects me.

Comment: @dado_eyad you can check if `request.path` is `/some/url/` before redirecting it.

Comment: @dado_eyad you are welcome :) Make sure to test more edge cases to be certain edge cases are covered :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use decorator function to check if user is activated and redirect him.
[How to write a custom decorator in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469159/how-to-write-a-custom-decorator-in-django)

Answer (score 0):

Use a view decorator.

Good article about it: http://passingcuriosity.com/2009/writing-view-decorators-for-django/

Comment: I have lots of views. I don't want to go through everyone and attach a decorator to it.