# cookie should be constructed first

Tags: python, django

I will call cookies before all web page. For this reason, I should create value key before all of the page or module is called. Before any of the page is called, cookie should be constructed first, for my case. How can I manage this? Where should I put `request.session['id']=Null` so that it will called first before any other page is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write a custom decorator to handle the situation.

You can read more about Decorators here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/decorators/

For example the `csrf_exempt` decorator allows a request to be processed without the csrf token facility in forms, very useful for JSON based requests.

```
@csrf_exempt
def new(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        json_data = simplejson.loads(request.raw_post_data)
        try:
```

Similarly have a custom decorator for ensuring cooking and use it as:

```
@ensure_cookie
def new(request):
...
```

Writing custom decorators: [How to write a custom decorator in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469159/how-to-write-a-custom-decorator-in-django)

Answer (score 0):

You can put this code in process_request or process_view method in custom [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware).