# check status every time a login required view is accessed in django

Tags: django, django-views, django-authentication

I have a status for delinquent users.  If a user has this status type for any number of reasons, I do not want them to access any views where a login is required.

How is this implemented in django?  Would I override the login_required annotation?  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you would make a decorator like `@login_required` in django. I will send you to a great question that shows you how to do this. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469159/how-to-write-a-custom-decorator-in-django) is the link.