# Django: Can we set permission to use an app?

Tags: python, django

In my Django site, I have several apps, each app is meant to be used by a specific group of users only. Let's say I have 2 groups of users: A and B. I have two apps: App1 whose URL starts with /app1, and App2 whose URL starts with /app2. I want to assign permission to use App1 to group A, and App2 to group B. Users from B can never access all URLs starting with /app1 and vice versa.

How can I do it?

Comment: Use the [`user_passes_test`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test) decorator.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write a custom decorator in django?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469159/how-to-write-a-custom-decorator-in-django)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *could* do this, but I would recommend against it.

You should be using the [`user_passes_test()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test) or the [`permission_required()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.permission_required) decorators on the views that implement `App1` and `App2`.

This would be achieved by adding something like this:

```
def in_group_a(user):
    return user.groups.filter(name="Group A").exists()

def in_group_b(user):
    return user.groups.filter(name="Group B").exists()

@user_passes_test(in_group_a)
def app1_view(request):
    ...

@user_passes_test(in_group_b)
def app2_view(request):
    ...
```

---

In order to acheive this as asked (with a *single* check based on the url prefix) you would have to have a single view per application, that was accessed via a url pattern like:

```
url(r'^app1/(?P<remaining_url>.*)$', 'app1.views.app1`)
```

Your view would then have to run `user_passes_test()` as above, and manually parse the `remaining_url` parameter to work out what to do next:

```
@user_passes_test(in_group_a)
def app1(request, remaining_url):
    # parse remaining_url and work out what to do
```

But that parsing and dispatching operation is exactly what the urlconf in Django is for.

In theory, you could create another app-specific urlconf (not referenced from your main `urls.py`) and manually use its API to re-dispatch `remaining_url` to a set of views.

Comment: but can you elaborate more about the reason why you recommend against it please?

Answer (score 7):

#### Given [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42743825/how-to-create-groups-and-assign-permission-during-project-setup-in-django/52041938#52041938),

Here is the code for adding all existing permissions of an app under a Group.
For exemple if you have App1 and App2, and you want to automatically create 2 groups named app1 and app2 containing permissions to the models of each app (respectively), try this :

#### For App1 on apps.py :

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.db.models.signals import post_migrate

class App1Config(AppConfig):
    name = 'app1'

    def ready(self):
        from .signals import populate_models
        post_migrate.connect(populate_models, sender=self)
```

#### Create a signals.py file that contains :

```
def populate_models(sender, **kwargs):
    from django.apps import apps
    from .apps import App1Config
    from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, Permission
    from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

    group_app, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name=App1Config.name)

    models = apps.all_models[App1Config.name]
    for model in models:
        content_type = ContentType.objects.get(
            app_label=App1Config.name,
            model=model
        )
        permissions = Permission.objects.filter(content_type=content_type)
        group_app.permissions.add(*permissions)
```

Do the same for App2

Then assign users to their groups.

For usage :

#### Create a file called permissions.py on each app and add :

```
from .apps import App1Config

def is_in_group_app1(user):
    return user.groups.filter(name=App1Config.name).exists()
```

#### In views.py use :

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required, user_passes_test
from .permissions import is_in_group_app1

@login_required(login_url='where_to_redirect')
@user_passes_test(is_in_group_app1) 
def myview(request):
    # Do your processing
```

For CBV :

```
@method_decorator(user_passes_test(is_in_group_app1), name='dispatch')
class LogListView(ListView):
    """ Displays all logs saved on App1 """
    model= Logger.objects.order_by('-date_created')
```

#### Create a folder named templatestag and subfolder app1 and a has_perms.py file :

```
from django import template
from app1.permissions import is_in_group_app1
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def has_perms(user):
    return is_in_group_app1(user)
```

#### In your template :

```
{% load has_perms %}

{% if request.user|has_perms %}
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="{% url 'app1:log' %}" class="nav-link">
            <i class="icon-history"></i>
            <span data-i18n="nav.dash.main">App1 Log</span>
        </a>
    </li>
{% endif %}
```

It took me a while to find all this process, so if it can help others :

## Enjoy ;) !