# How to create groups and assign permission during project setup in django?

Tags: python, django

I know I can create user groups and assign permission to them from the admin area in a django project. I can also create a group and assign permission to it by importing `Group` and `Permission` model from django's auth module.

What I want to know if there is any way I can create group and assign permission to them when I set up the project. So, if I have types of users, **Admin**, **Developer**, **Tester** and **Project Manager**. They are basically user groups which would have different permission level. I did not customize the `User` model and only can differentiate by the groups they are assigned to. So is there a way to create these groups and assign required permission to them like when permissions are created for admin when I run `python manage.py migrate`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can define a [`post_migrate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/signals/#post-migrate) signal to create required `User` and `Group` model instances if they don't exist already.

When you create an application in using `python manage.py startapp <app_name>`, it creates an `AppConfig` class in apps.py file.

You can specify which signal to call in `AppConfig` class definition. Say the signal is called `populate_models`. In that case, modify AppConfig to look like following:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.db.models.signals import post_migrate

class AppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'app'

    def ready(self):
        from .signals import populate_models
        post_migrate.connect(populate_models, sender=self)
```

And in signals.py define the `populate_models` function.

```
def populate_models(sender, **kwargs):
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    from django.contrib.auth.models import group
    # create groups
    # assign permissions to groups
    # create users
```

Comment: So this signal is emitted after the initial migration or every migration?  Do I need to check if the groups and permissions already exist and then add it?

Comment: Yes, signal is emitted after every `migrate` call. You will have to check if some `User` or `Group` already exists. You can use `get_or_create` shortcut.

Comment: Or alternatively you can check if `User.objects.count()` is zero.

Comment: There is no guarantee that this `post_migrate` handler will run after the handler defined by `django.contrib.auth` that creates the permissions. Hence this code could run and there are no permissions to assign to the groups.

Comment: @PenguinBrian do you know of a workaround for this?  (I suppose "run the migration twice" could work but...)

Comment: Unfortunately, no, I don't have any real solution. Otherwise, I would have added a solution here. The method we implemented was to add a button that is manually invoked on to the admin site.

Comment: @PenguinBrian are you sure there is no guarantee? This solution worked for me. At first I thought it wasn't working but it turns out the problem was my function was running in every post_migrate handler for every app (I was using the `@receiver` decorator). Once I properly connected passing the sender, the problem was solved. If Django decides the order in which the handlers are called in a deterministic way, this should always work. Do you know it to be otherwise? Is the order non-deterministic?

Comment: @Ariel @PenguinBrian from [the signal docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/signals/#listening-to-signals): the receiver functions are called in the order they were registered. And if you register your receiver on your app's `ready()` function (like how the snippet above and django's auth register the receiver), based on [the app docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/applications/#how-applications-are-loaded): the app's `ready()` stage is processed in the order of `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Answer (score 6):

#### According to @narenda-choudhary and @Rolando Cruz answer,

Here is the code for adding all existing permissions of an app under a Group.
For exemple if you have App1 and App2, and you want to automatically create 2 groups named app1 and app2 containing permissions to the models of each app (respectively), try this :

#### For App1 on apps.py :

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.db.models.signals import post_migrate

class App1Config(AppConfig):
    name = 'app1'

    def ready(self):
        from .signals import populate_models
        post_migrate.connect(populate_models, sender=self)
```

#### Create a signals.py file that contains :

```
def populate_models(sender, **kwargs):
    from django.apps import apps
    from .apps import App1Config
    from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, Permission
    from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

    group_app, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name=App1Config.name)

    models = apps.all_models[App1Config.name]
    for model in models:
        content_type = ContentType.objects.get(
            app_label=App1Config.name,
            model=model
        )
        permissions = Permission.objects.filter(content_type=content_type)
        group_app.permissions.add(*permissions)
```

Do the same for App2

Then assign users to their groups.

For usage :

#### Create a file called permissions.py on each app and add :

```
from .apps import App1Config

def is_in_group_app1(user):
    return user.groups.filter(name=App1Config.name).exists()
```

#### In views.py use :

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required, user_passes_test
from .permissions import is_in_group_app1

@login_required(login_url='where_to_redirect')
@user_passes_test(is_in_group_app1) 
def myview(request):
    # Do your processing
```

For CBV :

```
@method_decorator(user_passes_test(is_in_group_app1), name='dispatch')
class LogListView(ListView):
    """ Displays all logs saved on App1 """
    model= Logger.objects.order_by('-date_created')
```

#### Create a folder named templatestag and subfolder app1 and a has_perms.py file :

```
from django import template
from app1.permissions import is_in_group_app1
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def has_perms(user):
    return is_in_group_app1(user)
```

#### In your template :

```
{% load has_perms %}

{% if request.user|has_perms %}
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="{% url 'app1:log' %}" class="nav-link">
            <i class="icon-history"></i>
            <span data-i18n="nav.dash.main">App1 Log</span>
        </a>
    </li>
{% endif %}
```

It took me a while to find all this process, so if it can help others :

## Enjoy ;) !

Answer (score 1):

Note: scroll down to see my code implementation.

Django automatically populates the database at least on the following:

- [Populating `contenttypes.ContentType` for each defined models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#overview)
- [Populating `auth.Permission` for each default model permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#default-permissions)
- [Populating `sites.Site` with a default site example.com](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/sites/#enabling-the-sites-framework)

Looking at the source code ([`django.contrib.contenttypes`](https://github.com/django/django/tree/main/django/contrib/contenttypes), [`django.contrib.auth`](https://github.com/django/django/tree/main/django/contrib/auth), [`django.contrib.sites`](https://github.com/django/django/tree/main/django/contrib/sites)), I found the following pattern:

- Connect the receiver function to `post_migrate` signal inside the `AppConfig`.

  Example from [`django.contrib.sites.apps`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1bd6a7a0acc11e249fca11c017505ad39f15ebf6/django/contrib/sites/apps.py#L16):

  ```py
  class SitesConfig(AppConfig):
      ...

      def ready(self):
          post_migrate.connect(create_default_site, sender=self)
          ...
  ```
- Define the receiver function in the `management` module (instead of inside the `signal` module, which is usually used for defining the signal itself), and get the model class using `apps.get_model()` (instead of directly import the model class which could be inconsistent with the current state of migration).

  Example from [`django.contrib.sites.management`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1bd6a7a0acc11e249fca11c017505ad39f15ebf6/django/contrib/sites/management.py#L12-L15):

  ```py
  def create_default_site(app_config, verbosity=2, interactive=True, using=DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS, apps=global_apps, **kwargs):
      try:
          Site = apps.get_model('sites', 'Site')
      except LookupError:
          return

      if not router.allow_migrate_model(using, Site):
          return

      if not Site.objects.using(using).exists():
          ...
  ```

  The most important parameter here is `apps` for getting a model in the current migration state. If you use [multiple databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/multi-db/), you'll also need the `using` parameter to check if the model is allowed to be migrated and to be used in your query's [`.using()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#using). For other parameter explanations, check the [`post_migrate` signal docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/signals/#post-migrate).

##### Talk is cheap. Show me the code!

- I created an `assign_group_permissions()` function, which returns a receiver function that populates some permissions for a given group.

  `someproject/accounts/management.py`:

  ```py
  from django import apps as global_apps
  from django.db.models import Q


  def assign_group_permissions(group_name, permissions):
      def receiver(*args, apps=global_apps, **kwargs):
          try:
              Group = apps.get_model('auth', 'Group')
              Permission = apps.get_model('auth', 'Permission')
          except LookupError:
              return

          perm_q = Q()
          for perm in permissions:
              app_label, codename = perm.split('.')
              perm_q |= Q(content_type__app_label=app_label) & Q(codename=codename)

          group, _ = Group.objects.get_or_create(name=group_name)
          group.permissions.add(
              *Permission.objects.filter(perm_q)
          )

      return receiver
  ```
- Call the function inside each of the corresponding `AppConfig`. The example below shows how to assign view, add, change, and delete permissions of the `Announcement` model, which lives in `someproject.announcements` app to `event_admin` group.

  `someproject/announcements/apps.py`:

  ```py
  from django.apps import AppConfig
  from django.db.models.signals import post_migrate

  from someproject.accounts.management import assign_group_permissions


  class AnnouncementConfig(AppConfig):
      name = 'someproject.announcements'

      def ready(self):
          post_migrate.connect(assign_group_permissions(
              'event_admin',
              [
                  'announcements.add_announcement',
                  'announcements.change_announcement',
                  'announcements.delete_announcement',
                  'announcements.view_announcement',
              ],
          ))
  ```