# VariableDoesNotExist error on form submit using templatetag

Tags: django

I have the following form that works in its own view, that I am trying to set up as a template tag.

```
@login_required
@register.inclusion_tag('posts/new_post_form.html', takes_context = True)
def newpostform(context):
    request = context['request']
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        post_form_local = PostFormLocal(request.POST or None)
        user = request.user
        if post_form_local.is_valid():
            save_form = post_form_local.save(commit=False)
            save_form.user = request.user
            save_form.save()

            messages.success(request, 'Post Saved')

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/post/%d/' % save_form.id)
        else:
            return {'post_form_local': PostFormLocal(), 'user': user}
```

The form appears on a page fine by calling:

```
{% load newpost %}
{% newpostform %}
```

(and I am using Crispy Forms with this)

new_post_form.html looks like:

```
{% load url from future %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
            <form method="POST" action=""> {% csrf_token %}
            <h3>Create New Post</h3>
            {% crispy post_form_local %}
            </form>
```

The form appears ok, submits, but then comes up with an error:

VariableDoesNotExist at...(current page)

Failed lookup for key [post_form_local] in u"[{'False': False, 'None': None, 'True': True}, ]"

If I refresh this page, the post is saved and appears as normal - can't figure out what I am missing here, any thoughts?

Comment: That seems to be strange usage of template tag. Why not to use view? Your code actual looks like view function but it being template tag instead

Comment: still learning so probably doing it wrong - trying to adapt a view function to be able to use it on multiple pages instead of just one.

Comment: You should write a [custom view decorator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469159/how-to-write-a-custom-decorator-in-django) then. This processing shouldn't be done at the template level.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll look into doing it that way!

Comment: If you want to use same form on multiple pages then you need to set action attribute on those pages to point at one place. Again no need of template-tagging approach. Actually what is the point of using one form on several pages? Why not to have one template with form and include it everywhere? I think you're trying to be wisely predictive about what will happen in future. In very most of cases it is silly and excessive behavior that will take you to much more problems then benefits. Check in google for YAGNI principle