# Django Rest Framework - best way to an endpoint?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm learning Django + DRF + React and I reached the phase where it's time to protect some endpoints. Some are easier to protect, just a permission so only the user which created a particular object (and the admins) are able to see it. There is one endpoint which is tricky for me. It's a GET call and returns something like:

```
{book: "Who am I and how come",
 id: "whatever31",
 reading: ["user1", "user2"]}
```

I want to protect this endpoint based on the user making the request (Session auth) so only calls coming from `user1` and `user2` can access this object (also, not exposing `reading` field, but that's probably a different discussion). Should I use a custom permission on DRF view? Should I use a filter instead in `queryset` method? Maybe both?

Comment: Have you looked into creating an decorator on the controller? Sounds like this would be the place for it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469159/how-to-write-a-custom-decorator-in-django

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom permission just like creating an decorator, both of them match what you need:

```
class InReader(permissions.IsAuthenticated):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return request.user in obj.reading
```

Comment: And when getting these objects as list, I suppose only the one matching the permission will be returned?

Comment: This just return true or false to tell the request.user in obj.reading list or not.