# needed django users and subusers with limited permissions

Tags: python, django

I am a beginner of django.

I am trying to create a user below the admin: Let's call him **user1** and below this user there will be other users: **user2,user3,user4,..user50.**

So my question is:

An Admin can access everything, but users should access only some permissions. How can I implement this? So that each user has it's own permissions.

**User1** has permissions **1,2,3**

**User2** has permisison **2**

Can anyone help me?
 Thanks in advance

Comment: this question has been asked couple times. What have you tried? where is your code? next time google first, maybe you find something [link](https://www.vinta.com.br/blog/2016/controlling-access-a-django-permission-apps-comparison/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will use Django Permissions.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#topic-authorization

```
myuser.groups.set([group_list])
myuser.groups.add(group, group, ...)
myuser.groups.remove(group, group, ...)
myuser.groups.clear()
myuser.user_permissions.set([permission_list])
myuser.user_permissions.add(permission, permission, ...)
myuser.user_permissions.remove(permission, permission, ...)
myuser.user_permissions.clear()
```

and you will use included decorators or you will create custom decorators.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_staff

Custom Decorator:
[How to write a custom decorator in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469159/how-to-write-a-custom-decorator-in-django)